# <img> tags not working properly in HTML email

Tags: python, html, email, tags

I have been working in Python to send an HTML email newsletter. The Python part seems to be working properly, and I think the issue is with the email reading the HTML. Here is the HTML of the template I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <table align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding-bottom:20px" width="100%">
      <tr>
       <td align="center" style="Font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><img style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px" src="http://domain.com/logo.png" alt="logo" width="30%" /><table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80%" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px">
      <tr>
       <td align="left"><font color="#646466">Text<br><br><i>Text</i><br></font><h3><font color="#000000">Header</font></h3>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><img src="http://domain.com/link.png" alt="image" height="54" width="108" style="padding-right:10px" /></td>
       <td height="54" valign="top"><p style="margin:0px 0 0; padding-bottom:3px"><font color="#646466"><b>Text</b></font></p><font color="#646466" size="2">Text</font></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-bottom:10px"><img src="http://domain.com/link.png" alt="image" height="54" width="108" style="padding-right:10px" /></td><td height="54" valign="top"><p style="margin:0px 0 0; padding-bottom:3px"><font color="#646466"><b>Text</b></font></p><font color="#646466" size="2">Text</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><img src="http://domain.com/link.png" alt="image" height="54" width="108" style="padding-right:10px" /></td>
       <td height="54" valign="top"><p style="margin:0px 0 0; padding-bottom:3px"><font color="#646466"><b>Text</b></font></p><font color="#646466" size="2">Text</font></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <font color="#646466" size="2"><b>Text:</b> <i>text</i></font><h3><font color="#000000">Header</font></h3>
     <table>
      <tr> 
       <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><img src="http://domain.com/link.png" alt="image" height="54" width="108" style="padding-right:10px" /></td>
       <td height="54" valign="top"><p style="margin:0px 0 0; padding-bottom:3px"><font color="#646466"><b>Text</b></font></p><font color="#646466" size="2">Text</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><img src="http://domain.com/link.png" alt="image" height="54" width="108" style="padding-right:10px" /></td>
       <td height="54" valign="top"><p style="margin:0px 0 0; padding-bottom:3px"><font color="#646466"><b>Text</b></font></p><font color="#646466" size="2">Text</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><img src="http://domain.com/link.png" alt="image" height="54" width="108" style="padding-right:10px" /></td>
       <td height="54" valign="top"><p style="margin:0px 0 0; padding-bottom:3px"><font color="#646466"><b>Text</b></font></p><font color="#646466" size="2">Text</font></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <font color="#646466" size="2"><b>Text:</b> <i>Text</i></font><br><br><font color="#646466">Text<br><br>Text</font><br><br><font color="#646466" size="2"><i>Text.</i></font>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I save the source as a .html file and open it in Safari, everything appears as it should, and the images work. However, when I use the script and open in Gmail, some of the images are off (the first and the third image of just the first header in this instance), and I have no idea why since the code is the same for all of them. I am wondering if I am using a wrong tag or something that may not render properly for email. That is the only thing I can think of. In Gmail, when I inspect the images, the links for the non working images are off as well. The working ones are sent as http://domain.com/link.png and appear as the same. The non-working ones are sent as http://domain.com/link.png and appear as http://domain.com/l+ink.png (random '+' wrongfully in the string). If someone is more of an expert on HTML I would greatly appreciate the advice.

Comment: Format the code, people won't help you otherwise.

Comment: `width="30%"` is unfortunately not valid HTML. The _width_ attribute is already measured in pixels and required a integer value assigned to it. For instance `width="420"` means the image will be 420px wide. Also, it is good practice to ensure that your image also has a `height` attribute assigned to it, some older mail clients will read `height="0"` by default if you do not specify it.

Comment: Thank you @San for the edit. I was actually just going in now to fix it! :)

Comment: Anyway, @Abdul Fatir it is formatted now.

Comment: And @Frits, I tried changing the logo width to pixels rather than percentage, but to no avail. (The logo image, by the way, is never one that struggles. It is only the body images)

Comment: Welcome.. Happy Coding @user2287517

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue: Apparently new lines in HTML are significant for emails. The unformatted code with no new lines works fine in browsers, but sometimes breaks images in email for whatever reason. Adding in the new lines fixed the issue.